# How can I fetch mentions of another Twitter user?

Tags: twitter, get

Twitter API makes it easy to pull your own @mentions and @replies using [GET statuses/mentions_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/mentions_timeline).

So if I want to pull my own @mentions, I can authenticate and pull this using GET /statuses/mentions_timeline.

But what about tracking mentions of another user?

For example, how can I get a list of tweets that mention [@StackOverflow](https://twitter.com/StackOverflow)?

Needless to say, `/1.1/statuses/mentions_timeline?screen_name=stackoverflow` does not work.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to do this is using the [Search API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search).

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%40StackOverflow
```

That will give you all the Tweets that @StackOverflow will see when they look at their replies.

It may have a slightly different ordering - based on retweets etc - but it is a very close approximation.